# Angular2 image not showing

Tags: angular

Anytime i add a image tag in the html and i do something like this:

```
<img src="../resources/img/myimg.png">
```

The image doesn't show. Instead i get something this showing
[image: empty image]

I have tried putting `<base href="/">` in my index.html head but i get no changes.
What could be the cause of this?
What else must i do to make this work?

I also tried installing image-webpack-loader
Here is the content of my webpack.config.js file

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


// Webpack Config
var webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
    'main':       './src/main.browser.ts',
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills'], minChunks: Infinity }),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // .ts files for TypeScript
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      {
    test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
    loaders: [
      'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
      'image-webpack?{progressive:true, optimizationLevel: 7, interlaced: false, pngquant:{quality: "65-90", speed: 4}}'
    ]
  }
    ]
  }

};


// Our Webpack Defaults
var defaultConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src') ],
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 }
  },

  node: {
    global: 1,
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: 0,
    Buffer: 0,
    clearImmediate: 0,
    setImmediate: 0
  }
};

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
module.exports = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);
```

Comment: Click F12 and see what the console ouput is in your browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get out of `base href` scope, you should move your assets inside `src` directory and after give path e.g `./resources` it will be `src/resources`.

Comment: My folder structure i like this `src` contains `app` and `app` contains `resources` folder and a folder for each separate component. It is from the html layout of a component that i am using relative layout to link the img files stored inside resources folder.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I now understand what `base href` does. Quite embarrassing though.