# Change image source on condition Angular2

Tags: angular

My Application is either *active* (true) or *inactive* (!actice).
I want to change my image source for each state:

`<img [src]="{'../../resources/images/pause.png':active, '../../resources/images/play.png':!active}"`

(typical *boolean ? valueA : valueB* isn't correct)

The code is running but the images aren't found.
Changing the path didn't help. Maybe you can...

UPDATE
folder structure

`app
|
+--components
|    |
|    +--header (html, ts,...)
|
+--resources
|    |
|    +--images (png)`

Comment: Can you share the folder structure of your app, and the img path that your browser try to load ? BTW, you should export your logic into a component method for a better readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jxMe5tohBbhefMm06Vjk?p=preview) Demo

Don't put the curly braces `{}` in the quotes `""` and make sure the paths are correct. Eitherwise this is how you would do it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h2>{{active ? "Front": "Back"}} of '18 Civic Type R</h2>
        <label> Toggle Front and Back View
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="active" />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <img [src]="active ? frontPath : backPath">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  active:boolean = false;

  frontPath:string = "http://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/styles/fit_980x551/public/images/news-article/carousel/2016/09/a4705f0aaad0587c653b37b03409b0a0/78932_new_civic_type_r_prototype_breaks_cover_in_paris-1.jpg?itok=Few4WV6D";

  backPath:string = "http://tophondacars.com/wp-content/uploads/2018-Honda-Civic-Type-R-pwe.jpg";

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

## OR

You could use `*ngIf` and just show/hide (add/remove technically) when you want to.

[*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

> Removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.
>
> If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a falsy value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

```
<img *ngIf="active" [src]="../../resources/images/pause.png">
<img *ngIf="!active" [src]="../../resources/images/play.png">
```

Comment: Good! Glad to help out!

Comment: this helped too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635649/angular2-image-not-showing